# Python For Loop through range

Tags: python, loops

I created a class to calculate loans principal and interest. However, I have no idea why, but my python code calculates values starting with month 2, instead of 1. All values are correct, except that it sets values for month 1 as 0 values. I can't understand what I am doing wrong, I've tried to change range to `for t in range(0, len(self.data['month']+1))` , python shows an error: `ValueError: array length 90361 does not match index length 90360.`. Here is my code:

```
class Collat: 


  def __init__(self, filename, collateral_activity, Pif_Prn = 0, Pif_Int=0):
    self.filename=filename
    self.data=self.data[['month','loan_number','p_prepay','loan_type','current_upb','current_interest_rate', 'DQ']]
    self.collateral_activity = collateral_activity
    self.month=self.data['month'].tolist()
    self.p_cure= self.data['p_prepay'].tolist()
    self.upb=self.data['current_upb'].tolist()
    self.int_r=self.data['current_interest_rate'].tolist()
    self.type= self.data['loan_type'].tolist()
    self.dq=self.data['DQ'].tolist()
    self.Pif_Prn= [Pif_Prn]
    self.Pif_Int = [Pif_Int]
   
    
    


    
  def calint(self, t):
    return  self.int_r[t]/12 *(self.month[t]+self.dq[t]+1)
    


  def generate(self):
    for t in range(1, len(self.data['month']+1)):
        self.Pif_Prn.append(self.p_prepay[t] * self.upb[t] )
        self.Pif_Int.append(self.Pif_Prn[t]* self.calint(t))
        
    
    lists= {'Prepaid Principal':self.Pif_Prn, 'Prepaid Int':self.Pif_Int }
    loan_activity = pd.DataFrame(lists)
    loan_activity.to_csv(self.collateral_activity, header=True, index=False)
```

and the output looks like this: skipping calculations for month 1:

```
month  Prepaid Principal    Prepaid Interest
  1       0                     0
  2       55685                2546
```

Comment: Do you really not see this?  In your `__init__` function, what are the values you store as the first entries in `self.Pif_Prn` and `self.Pif_Int`?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
It appears that your starting values are 0, instead of your intended first-month values.

Comment: Yes, I really don't see. I haven't stored any values, the first loan with 360 periods followed by the next loan and for the next loan everything is correct starting with month 1, not 2

Answer (score 1):

In `def generate` it seems that you wrote `1` instead of `0`
In python, list indexes start at `0`, so that would skip the first element

```
def generate(self):
    for t in range(0, len(self.data['month']+1)):
                 # ^ Previously 1
```

Comment: if I change it to 0 then Python shows an error : ValueError: array length 90361 does not match index length 90360. If I change it to range(0, len(self.data['month']) it shows :array length 90361 does not match index length 90360

Comment: @Camilla there are quite a few mistakes in the code actually. First of all `self.p_prepay` is not defined anywhere.